# How to get address range for different memory section in C?

Tags: c

[Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/) says:

> A typical memory representation of C program consists of following  sections.
>
> 1. Text segment
> 2. Initialized data segment
> 3. Uninitialized data segment
> 4. Stack
> 5. Heap

But, how to get start address and end address of each section?

Comment: Why do you need this information?  The text segment is your code.  The initialized data segment is filled in with the initial values of all initialized _global_ variables.  The uninitialized data segment is allocated with enough space for all _global_ variables with no initial values.  The stack and heap are dynamically managed (the stack is managed by the system, the heap is through memory allocations such as malloc()/free() or the underlying brk()/cbrk() calls.

Comment: This is highly implementation defined. It depends on the operating system, and possibly the compiler. No answer is possible without identitying the OS and the compiler, and if you didn't even realize that it was necessary to specify the OS and the compiler, then whatever reason you think you need this for, it must be a wrong reason.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to get the beginning and ending address of each memory segment is to incorporate a linker command file and within that file place a label at each start and end of each memory segment.

For `gcc` (and ld) this link should tell you everything you need to know:

`https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html`